# How to get values of EditText And RadioButton and send it via HTTP Post

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xmlhttprequest

I am new in Android programming. Could any tell me way to solve the following issue?

I make a XML file with following codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="com.royalrandhawa.xemp.SplashScreen">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mainSearch"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:textColor="#373737"
            android:textColorHint="#bfbfbf"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="This is your field...."
            android:background="@drawable/mainsearch"
            />

            <Button
            android:text="Surf Now!"
            android:id="@+id/surfNowBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="send"
            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <RadioButton
                android:text="Filter Search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/filtersearch"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="false"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:text="Trace my activities"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/traceme"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout details are:
user enter his **query** in *EditText* and there is some other option like **Filter Search** and **Trace Activities** in *RadioButtons*.

I want these:

After Click on **Search** button, get value of **EditText** and *check if* either or both **radiobuttons** are selected then make two variable with **fsVr and tmVr** and set there values to **true**. and start *new activity name* **Result**

After that send these values to a **URL** with **HTTP POST** method.
and show the *server response* in **TextView** in **Result (Activity)**

Thank You!

Comment: You've pretty much explained exactly what you need to do. Is there a specific problem you have?

Comment: provide us with some code which you tried... so we can help if you are running into problem...

Comment: @cvanbeek I don't know about JAVA codes I only know about XML files in android studio. Please send me full codes of JAVA , its a humble request

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html 
That is a link to the documentation on accessing xml elements in your java code. You can find many different ways to do HTTP requests by doing a Google search. Different methods work best depending on the scope of the project.

Comment: I will warn you it will be very hard to write an Android app without being familiar with java so you may want to take a class about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your `xml` is wrong. It should be like that

You need to create two different `RadioGroup` and both have only one `RadioButton` because of your requirement is either or both `radiobuttons` are selected

And java code is here

```
private void initview1() {

    RadioButton filtersearch = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.filtersearch);
    RadioButton traceme = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.traceme);
    Button Search_Buttom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Search_Buttom);
    EditText mainSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mainSearch);

    Search_Buttom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Boolean fsVr = false, tmVr = false;
            String search_data = mainSearch.getText().toString();
            fsVr = filtersearch.isChecked();
            tmVr = traceme.isChecked();
// go to your new activity with required data..
        }
    });
}
```